# Kubuntu unlock screen - keyboard trigger and auto-focus

Tags: kubuntu, kde, customization, kde5

I just switched from Ubuntu/Gnome to give Kubuntu/KDE a try. I often suspend/lock my system. The unlock screen when restarted from suspend seems to require a mouse event to trigger it so it displays the password entry text box and the keyboard focus is often not in the password box so I need to move the mouse there and click.

The behavior of Gnome/gdm was such that I could just open the cover of my machine and type my password without any mouse events required. I liked this best. Can I configure sddm to behave that way? Or is there an alternative DM I should look into?

Comment: This behaviour began after a recent update. I use kubuntu and it worked fine until then. If it's not a security concern, it would be handy to have the original behaviour back.
It may have been an accidental bug introduced while fixing the onscreen keyboard bug related to unlocking.
Maybe it warrants a bug report?